# System.Timers.Timer drifting by 1 second a day when autoreset is true

Tags: powershell

Has anyone noticed there is drift in the timer when autoreset is true?

I've been running a powershell script for four days and have noticed that it drifts by 1 second a day. I'm considering not using autoreset but resetting the timer whenever an event is received, i.e.

$timer.autoreset = $false

$timer.interval = (61 - [int](get-date).toString("ss"))*1000 # 1 second after the minute mark

$timer.start()

However i'd be interested in a more elegant solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _1 second after the minute mark_.. `[int](get-date).toString("ss")` gives you a number ranging 0-59. Subtract that from 61 --> range 2-61, so it seems to me you are skipping one second here..

Comment: I want to be sure that the next tick is in the next minute. I'm writing a lightweight scheduler so every minute needs to be processed - but not every second. The drift I observe in the system.timers.timer class means that approximately every 60 days a minute will be skipped and I want better accuracy than that.

I've since found that '(get-date).second' is better for finding the current second.